# ASP.NET Web API - App.config does not work?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have simple self-host Web API application. I installed *EnityFramework6* package and added following lines in *App.config* under *<enityframework>* section:

```
<contexts>
    <context type="simple_api.MyContext, simple_api">
        <databaseInitializer type="simple_api.MyInitializer, simple_api" />
    </context>
</contexts>
```

Initializer class is like following:

```
public class MyInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>
{
    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        Console.log("My seed method");
        var persons = new List<Person> { };
        var john = new Person() { Firstname = "John", Lastname = "Doe" };
        context.Persons.Add(john);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I enabled and created migration, but the problem is that running it does not trigger my *Seed* method:

```
PM> Update-Database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [201805210804206_initial].
Applying explicit migration: 201805210804206_initial.
Running Seed method.
```

I also tried changing *App.config*, but It seems to be totally ignored, because `<context type="foobar, nomatterwhatishere">` does not trigger any warning nor error.

What can be the problem?

--

By the way, when I configured *log4net*, file was ignored also and I have to call  `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()`. Maybe there is similar thing for EntityFramework?

Comment: You haven't put any value for Database Initializer.
Checkout http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong: config file works, but *Seed* method for *DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges* is not triggered. I replaced it with ***DropCreateDatabaseAlways*** and after querying model it throwed exception:

```
Failed to set database initializer of type 'simple_api.MyInitializer, simple_api' for DbContext type 'simple_api.MyContext, simple_api' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.
```

After some debugging I figured out that namespace is `simple_api`, but assembly name is `simple-api`, so configuration should be as follows:

```
...
<entityframework>
    <contexts>
        <context type="simple_api.MyContext, simple-api">
            <databaseInitializer type="simple_api.MyInitializer, simple-api" />
        </context>
    </contexts>
    ...
</entityframework>
...
```

Now everything is working, but I am not sure why Seed was 
 not called for *DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges*.